# How to use flask to check whether every folder has specific files or not and using jinja2 to show the result?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am now trying to check whether every folder has specific files or not.
First, I create two list to store the `is_file` result.
`folderlist[folder1,folder2]`, `has_data[file1 ok,file2 nok,file1 ok, file2 ok]`
But I don't know how to use `jinja2` to deal with them.
I want the output can be like below.

```
folder1
  file1 ok
  file2 nok
folder2
  file1 ok
  file2 ok
```

And below is my code to check file.
Could you give me some advice or better solution?

```
        def has_data():
          folderlist = []
          has_data = []
          for root, dirs, files in walk(target_folder):
              qq = list(root.split('\\'))
              filefolder = qq[-1]
              folderlist.append(filefolder)
              file1_site = os.path.join(target_folder+'\\'+filefolder+'\\' + 'file1.txt')
              file2_site = os.path.join(target_folder+'\\'+filefolder+'\\' + 'file2.txt')
              if not os.path.isfile(file1_site):
                has_data.append('file1.txt  NOK')
              else:
                has_data.append('file1.txt  OK')
              if not os.path.isfile(file2_site):
                has_data.append('file2.txt  NOK')
              else:
                has_data.append('file2.txt  OK')
          del folderlist [0]
          del has_data [0]
          return render_template('hasdata.html',folderlist=folderlist,has_data=has_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve your problem directly, don't know values of those list. But you can wrap your html output in `pre` tag for preformatted text and add `-` sign to for loop.

From jinja2 documentation:

> You can also strip whitespace in templates by hand. If you add a minus sign (-) to the start or end of a block (e.g. a For tag), a comment, or a variable expression, the whitespaces before or after that block will be removed

So your template can look something like this to get output you need:

```
...
<pre>
  {% for folder in folderlist -%}
    {{ folder }}
      {% for file in has_data -%}
        {{ file }}
      {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</pre>
...
```

Comment: But there has a problem.
It will put all has_data in every folder.
Like this 
`Folder1
      file1 ok
      file1 ok ... ...`
I want  first `file1 ok` to `folder1` and second `file1 ok` to `folder2`.

Comment: I know, but it's better than, for simplicity to split `has_data` into two arrays, one for each folder. Or make `has_data` accept array as element, for example `has_data=[ ['file1 ok','file2 nok], ['file1 ok', 'file2 ok'] ]`